# "match or null" query in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Suppose I have an index with all movies released from 2010 to 2019; 
How can I translate this query in SQL to ElasticSearch?

```
Select *
From movies
Where 
    releaseDate between '2018-01-01' and '2019-01-01' and
    gender is like 'action' and
    (mainActorId = 42 or mainActorId is null)
```

I want all the action movies from 2018 with an specific main actor or no main actor at all. How would I translate that to an ElasticSearch query?

From what I've read so far in the documentation, I could use something like this:

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "releaseDate":{  
                     "from":"2018-01-01T00:00:01.531Z",
                     "to":"2019-01-01T00:00:01.531Z",
                     "include_lower":true,
                     "include_upper":true,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "gender":[  
                     "action"
                  ],
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            },
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "mainActorId":[  
                     42,
                     56
                  ],
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":[  
            {  
               "exists":{  
                  "field":"mainActorId",
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   }
}
```

But that's not giving me any hits, even though there are action movies released in 2018 with the main actor I want (or no main actors at all). If I take away the "must_not exist" clause, the query works fine and gives me the action movies with the main actors I want, but I also want action movies with no main actors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great start so far!! You're almost there, see the query below, it should do just what you expect:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "releaseDate": {
              "from": "2018-01-01T00:00:01.531Z",
              "to": "2019-01-01T00:00:01.531Z",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "gender": [
              "action"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "mainActorId"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "mainActorId": [
              42,
              56
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you are the man, Val! This gave me the the hits that I was expecting, once again you saved my life Val :D...

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that helped you!

Comment: Hi Val, I found something wrong with this query. The query returns me the movies from 2018 with all actors. It doesn't let me "filter" the actors that I want. For example, I want action movies from 2018 where the mainActor is Tom Cruise or null, and it returns me all action movies from 2018 with all actors... apparently the "terms" doesn't work inside the should... do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I already tried using "should":["bool":{{"must_not":[{"exists"}],"filter":{"terms":{"mainActorId":[1,2,3]}}}] but it doesn't work either... I'm getting really confused with these elasticsearch queries

Comment: There's no reason terms wouldn't work in a should clause. Something else must be off. Since this question is closed, I suggest you create a new one with the exct query you're making + sample documents + the results you get and what you expect.